# Paperclip directory pluralization problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've had a system thats been running fine for ages using Rails 3 & Paperclip 2.3.6 for members images.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :business
   has_attached_file :data, :styles => {:normal => ["665x443#", :jpg],:thumb => ["104x50#", :jpg]}, :convert_options => {:all => "-channel RGB -strip -quality 80"}
end
```

Now for some reason the route for the images has changed to **/system/data/** instead of previous **/system/datas/**

I cant figure out whats happened. All of the images still reside in /system/datas/ and a member uploaded some new images and Paperclip has put them in /system/data/

Anyone have any ideas whats happened? I cant figure it out. Thanks.

EDIT: Ok, I had a test box still on Rails 3.0.3. My Release version was on 3.0.7. If I roll back to Rails 3.0.3 it's working again - the path /system/data/ becomes /system/datas/ again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3.0.5 introduced some additional inflections which meant 'datas' was no longer used as the plural of 'data', which broke the directory naming for Paperclip!

Answer (score -1):

According to the paperclip documentation you can specify a path for saving images in your model using the :path option and providing a path.

You can find the documentation [here](http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.11/Paperclip/Attachment%3apath).

Comment: OK, thanks. However, I'm trying to figure out whats changed. Rails gets updated and is now 3.0.7, but Paperclip is locked on 2.3.6. So why am I now having the directory problem when it was working OK?

Comment: I wonder if upon it breaking after the update to 3.0.5 if a git bisect would've shown you what happened.